# Jquery Carousel Issues

Tags: jquery, plugins, width, carousel

I am using Jquery's Just Another Carousel plugin and I'm having issues with something which I am not sure and because of this it's not working. I'm using this plugin because I need fixed height rather than fixed width.

any help?

Comment: ? Can't understand what your problem is or what the issue with the sample you linked is supposed to be. It works just fine for me. Please try to use clearer english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cache timing issue, DOM ready doesn't mean all the images are loaded..and when they're not you see the problem in that page (some of the last images to load get left out).

Instead of this:

```
$(init); // on DOM load
```

You should use this, which fires after images are ready:

```
$(window).load(init);
```